# Django Rest Framework how to check an object is exists or not?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to check if an object is exists or not and this is how I do:

```
try:
    control = Card.objects.filter(cc_num = cc_number)[0]
    exists = True
except (IndexError):
    exists = False
```

It works but I wonder if there is a more practical way to do?

(The reason I use `except(IndexError)` is I'm finding the object with typing `[0]` to end of `model.objects.filter()`.)

Note: `cc_num` is unique.

Comment: There are many ways how you could check the existence of an object in Django, however, it highly depends on the context where you are using it in DRF.  Usage of `queryset` class attributes or `get_queryset` methods could help you to eliminate the need to manually check the existence of objects in your views.
Your code above could be also useful and slightly optimised `control = Card.objects.filter(cc_num = cc_number).first()`  control in this case might be either an instance of `Card` object or None.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
if model.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
    # at least one object satisfying query exists
else:
    # no object satisfying query exists
```

Check this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

Answer (score 2):

try this:
use Card.objects.get() since cc_num is unique, and only one object will be retrieved if it exists

```
try:
    controls = Card.objects.get(cc_num == cc_number)
    #do something
except DoesNotExist:
    #do something in case not
```

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/check+if+a+value+exist+in+a+model+Django

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,import this

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
   controls = Card.objects.get(cc_num == cc_number)
   #do something
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
   #do something in case not
```